# statsmodel GLM fit_constrained - object of type 'int' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels, glm

I'm using statsmodel to fit a GLM (Negative Binomial) and I want to add some constraints to the fit

In the regression, there are five parameters involved: `a,b,c,d` and the constraint consists in `a+b=0`

The relevant code is the following:

```
model = sm.GLM(y_metrics, X, family=sm.families.NegativeBinomial(alpha=1))
result = model.fit_constrained("a + b = 0")
```

but when I run the code I have the following error:

```
     44 
     45         model = sm.GLM(y_metrics, X, family=sm.families.NegativeBinomial(alpha=1))
---> 46         result = mod.fit_constrained("a + b = 0")
     47 
     48 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/genmod/generalized_linear_model.py in fit_constrained(self, constraints, start_params, **fit_kwds)
   1345 
   1346         # same pattern as in base.LikelihoodModel.t_test
-> 1347         lc = DesignInfo(self.exog_names).linear_constraint(constraints)
   1348         R, q = lc.coefs, lc.constants
   1349 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/patsy/design_info.py in linear_constraint(self, constraint_likes)
    534           di.linear_constraint("x1 = x2 = 3")
    535         """
--> 536         return linear_constraint(constraint_likes, self.column_names)
    537 
    538     def describe(self):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/patsy/constraint.py in linear_constraint(constraint_like, variable_names)
    401             if not isinstance(code, str):
    402                 raise ValueError("expected a string, not %r" % (code,))
--> 403             tree = parse_constraint(code, variable_names)
    404             evaluator = _EvalConstraint(variable_names)
    405             constraints.append(evaluator.eval(tree, constraint=True))

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/patsy/constraint.py in parse_constraint(string, variable_names)
    235 
    236 def parse_constraint(string, variable_names):
--> 237     return infix_parse(_tokenize_constraint(string, variable_names),
    238                        _ops, _atomic)
    239 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/patsy/constraint.py in _tokenize_constraint(string, variable_names)
    177 
    178     # Prefer long matches:
--> 179     variable_names = sorted(variable_names, key=len, reverse=True)
    180     variable_re = "|".join([re.escape(n) for n in variable_names])
    181 

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Any idea why it is happening? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: The names in the constraint string have to be the exog_names or param_names in the model. There are no parameters `a` and `b` in your model

Comment: unless `X` is a DataFrame that includes columns "a" and "b"

Comment: right, X is a pandas Dataframe containing a,b,c and d

Comment: check `mod.exog_names`. Note: you define `model` but then you fit `mod`, maybe that refers to something else

Comment: Sorry, it was just a typo. I edited the question. Anyway, when I print model.exog_names I got `[ "a", "b", "c", "d"] `

Comment: Then I'm out of candidates. It fails in the string parsing, so something is wrong with the constraint. You need to make a replicable example.